# need a USB boot tool to diagnose internal sata drive of netbook

Tags: hard-drive

I need to find out what the problem of the internal drive is before I take the laptop apart , which will take some time due to the nature of this laptop (asus 1016p).
I need a tool that I can boot off (usb only) and run diagnostics on this drive.

is there anything free i can download?

Comment: http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?content=TRINITY_RESCUE_KIT____CPR_FOR_YOUR_COMPUTER&front_id=12&lang=en&locale=en or http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a tool for your problem :

http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage

Description:

> SystemRescueCd is a Linux system rescue disk available as a bootable
>   CD-ROM or [USB stick](http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_How_to_install_SystemRescueCd_on_an_USB-stick) for administrating or repairing your system and
>   data after a crash. It aims to provide an easy way to carry out admin
>   tasks on your computer, such as creating and editing the hard disk
>   partitions. It comes with a lot of linux software such as system tools
>   (parted, partimage, fstools, ...) and basic tools (editors, midnight
>   commander, network tools). It can be used for both Linux and windows
>   computers, and on desktops as well as servers. This rescue system
>   requires no installation as it can be booted from a CD/DVD drive or
>   USB stick, but it can be installed on the hard disk if you wish. The
>   kernel supports all important file systems (ext2/ext3/ext4, reiserfs,
>   btrfs, xfs, jfs, vfat, ntfs), as well as network filesystems (samba
>   and nfs).